# Deployment of masterpage goes wrong if .wsp is used

Tags: custom-masterpage, solution-deployment

i have a custom master page layout. The problem is that it works great if i install it with the Web-interface or with SPD.. Unfortunately everytime i try to deploy it using VS either direct deployment or as a .wsp via powershell and activate it using SPD it says on the sp-site that this masterpage is not valid and i should choose another one.

Am i missing some information in the elements.xml or the feature?

little bit lost..

kind regards,

peter

Comment: Are you referring to a Master Page or a Page Layout?  They are two different things.

Comment: im referring to a master page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Elements.xml and make sure that you have the `Type="GhostableInLibrary"` attribute included on the `<File ... />` line that references your master page. You may also need a `<Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x010105" />` child element as well.

i.e.

```
<File Url="MyCustomMaster.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" >
    <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="4" />
    <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x010105" />
</File>
```

Comment: thanks so far - the error doesn't appear in the solution gallery anymore - still now im confronted with this little hurdle: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2009/06/20/cannot-convert-type-microsoft-sharepoint-webcontrols-cssregistration-to-system-web-ui-iattributeaccessor-beware-of-this-in-custom-master-page-for-custom-publishing-site-definition.aspx i will get at it tomorrow and check where something is wrong!

Comment: cleaned the master page from SPD tags and it works finally..

Comment: Ah, yes.  You've got to love Designer!  No, really! You don't have a choice so you might as well start repeating that to yourself now in the hopes of eventually believing it.